# removeEventListener is not executing on 'keydown' event

Tags: javascript, textbox, addeventlistener

I have a dashboard site where the user can switch between a list view or grid view by pressing the "l" or "g" hotkeys anywhere on the site window. Since this eventListener is called on the 'keydown' event for the entire window, this leads to the problem where the site will switch views if the user ever inputs "l" or "g" when typing in the search text box on the site.

To mitigate this issue, my approach is to add an eventListener on the search text box element for the 'keydown' element that removes the eventListener for the 'keydown' on the window element. I have then implemented a timer that starts the countdown for 3 seconds after the user has stopped typing (by adding an eventListener on the search text box for the 'keyup' event).

After 3 seconds have elapsed without the 'keydown' event being triggered on the search text-box, I then add the 'keydown' eventListener back to the window element once again.

**JS Code**

```js
let timer;
let timeInterval = 3000; // milliseconds so equates to 3 seconds

let searchTextBox = document.querySelector("#search-textbox");

if (typeof (searchTextBox) != 'undefined' && searchTextBox != null) { // check if the search text box was successfully created and inserted into the DOM
    searchTextBox.addEventListener('keydown', function () { // when key is pressed on the search text box, remove the window eventListener
        window.removeEventListener('keydown', addViewHotKeys);
    });

    searchTextBox.addEventListener('keyup', function () { // start the timer after a key is released
        console.log('key lifted');
        clearTimeout(timer); // clear the timeout if it was already set
        if (searchTextBox.value) { // if the textbox has any input inside, set the timer to execute the finishedTyping function after the timeInterval milliseconds has elapsed
            timer = setTimeout(finishedTyping, timeInterval);
        }
    });

    function finishedTyping() {
        addViewHotKeys();
        console.log('times up');
    }
}

// Detect hotkeys for easy navigation on index.html
function addViewHotKeys() {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
        if (event.key === 'l') {
            if (state.display !== 'list') {
                state.display = 'list';
                renderViewSelection();
                renderDashboardPlane();
            }
        } else if (event.key === 'g') {
            if (state.display !== 'grid') {
                state.display = 'grid';
                renderViewSelection();
                renderDashboardPlane();
            }
        }
    });
}

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    addViewHotKeys();
});
```

My 'keydown' and 'keyup' eventListeners on the search textBox successfully trigger (and the timer works as intended by executing the finishedTyping function after 3 seconds). However, for the 'keydown' eventListener on the search box, it is not removing the eventListener on the window element and I am still unable to find a reason as to why this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

A much cleaner way of solving this problem might be to use the search text box [focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focus_event) and [blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) events, rather than a timer on key input.

The below example removes the keydown event listener when you focus on the input element and adds it again when the input element loses focus. You could apply the same technique to include any other input elements.

```js
let searchTextBox = document.querySelector("#search-textbox");

// Detect hotkeys for easy navigation on index.html
function addViewHotKeys(event) {
  if (event.key === 'l') {
    console.log('l');
    
    // useful code here
    
  } else if (event.key === 'g') {
    console.log('g');
    
    // useful code here
  }
}

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    searchTextBox.addEventListener('focus', function() {
        window.removeEventListener('keydown', addViewHotKeys);
    });
    
    searchTextBox.addEventListener('blur', function() {
        window.addEventListener('keydown', addViewHotKeys);
    });
    
    window.addEventListener('keydown', addViewHotKeys);
});
```

```html
<p>Press the l or g key to log that letter to the console, except when the input has focus:</p>
<input id="search-textbox" type="search" value="" placeholder="search-textbox" />
```